# jq: how to select entries containing element in a mixed (scalar/list) value

Tags: json, jq

I need to select values that have lists with a special element in some attributes:

```
Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - s3:GetObject
      - s3:ListBucket
    Resource:
      - Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
            - bucket*
      - Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
            - bucket*
    
  - Effect: Allow
    Action: cloudformation:*
    Resource:
      - Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:cloudformation:'
            - Ref: AWS::Region
            - ':'
            - Ref: AWS::AccountId
            - :stack/
            - Ref: AWS::StackName
            - /*
```

In this example, the first element must be selected, because its `Action` contains `s3:GetObject`.

If I try to use `select` here, it does not work, because in the second element, `Action` does not contain a list, and `contains` can't iterate over it.

```
$ cat action.yaml | yq -y '.Statement[].Action[]|contains("s3:GetObject")
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over string ("cloudforma...)
```

I can check if the element contains a list, using `type`:

```
$ cat action.yaml | yq -y '.Resources.InstanceRolePolicy.Properties.PolicyDocument.Statement[]|select(.Action|select(type=="array"))'
```

But how can I combine both checks in our `select` ?

Comment: jq or yq? You show YAML and yq commands, but the tags and title all say jq/JSON.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Does it really matter? YAML is automatically converted into JSON, and then `jq`-style query is applied

Comment: Well, if I take your YAML input and try to parse it with jq, then yes, it matters.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: YAML is automatically converted to JSON by yq. I could just convert it to JSON myself, and use `jq` in the query instead of `yq`. My question would stay the same. The answer is already found, and it is correct

Comment: Oh. You're using kislyuk/yq, and not mikefarah/yq. The latter doesn't error for your first attempt, but returns `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `select(type=="array")` after traversing to an element (here `.Statement[].Action` ) but before trying to iterate over its items (`[]`):

```bash
.Statement[].Action | select(type=="array")[] | contains("s3:GetObject")
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DtC4zqLFTto)

Actually, there is a built-in [shortcut](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L54) to `select(type=="array")` called `arrays`, so this is equivalent:

```bash
.Statement[].Action | arrays[] | contains("s3:GetObject")
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1GRkcySZNy9)

Comment: I think we are almost there. The only problem is that instead of `.Action` as the result we need the whole subtrees where `.Action` matches the search (I need that my first "broken" example is also returning `.Action` only, but I need the whole tree)

Comment: Do you mean `.Statement[] | select(.Action | arrays[] | contains("s3:GetObject"))`? @IgorChubin